# How to stream video from node.js into kafka with kafka stream?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, video-streaming

I need to implement a video streaming with the help of kafka.I am able to stream the video to the browser with the help of node.js.But I want to know how to stream video from node.js to kafka producer and also the consumer.

I got this code for sending text messages but i want to send the live video.

```
const Transform = require('stream').Transform;
const ProducerStream = require('./lib/producerStream');
const _ = require('lodash');
const producer = new ProducerStream();
const stdinTransform = new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    decodeStrings: true,
    transform (text, encoding, callback) {
        text = _.trim(text);
        console.log(`pushing message ${text} to ExampleTopic`);
        callback(null, {
            topic: 'ExampleTopic',
            messages: text
        });
    }
});
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.pipe(stdinTransform).pipe(producer);
```

Comment: Kafka is not intended for file streaming... How would you ensure that the file arrived in order?

Comment: But i want to create a heavy load so i took video as my input.I successfully implemented the live streaming with the help of python and kafka but the performance was not good.

Comment: Well, there's lots of factors there to improve performance, but node-rdkafka and confluent-kafka-python share the same underlying C library, so I'm not sure why switching to Node helps you here

Comment: Here i need to send  both audio and video .So with the help of node.js it is very easy to send both audio and video.Is there any way to change the above code for video streaming.

Comment: I dont work with video processing, but Kafka accepts bytes of any format, so that should be something for you to research... However, again - how you determine the start/end of a certain audio/video feed in Kafka seems foreign to me

Comment: We have a method which streams video as chunks to the browser.Now that we plan to send this data (in chunks) to the producer Stream. I guess we are right theoretically however it seems quite a challenge to send the data through kafka stream.

**res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'})
    var rs=fs.createReadStream('video.mp4');
    rs.pipe(res); //here we want to connect the kafka**

Comment: I don't know Node, so however you chunk that data, and create a Kafka producer is really all that you need to figure out. Based on the question, it seems you've not tried creating a Kafka producer in Node, so I suggest starting there before worrying about video streams